# Youtube Analytics and Reporting API doesn't generate new reports for job created

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

Some days ago I used the code below to create a new job on Youtube's Analytics and Reporting API. The `createTime` for this job is `2022-07-25T13:54:51Z`.

```
def create_job(token, reportTypeId, name):
    print(F"START: RUNNING create_job")

    data = {"reportTypeId": reportTypeId,
            "name": name}

    resp = requests.post("https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/jobs",
                         headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token},
                         json = data)
    
    print(F"DONE: RUNNING create_job")

    return None
```

I waited the 24h for the API to generate the reports, and when I ran the code below to list the existing reports for that job, I got urls for distinct dates.

```
def list_job_reports(token, jobId):
    print(F"START: RUNNING list_job_reports")

    # Fetching all existing reports for this job
    url = f"https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/jobs/{jobId}/reports"

    resp = requests.get(url,
                        headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token})
    resp = json.loads(resp.text)

    # Wrangling resp into dictionary with report date and url
    reports_dict = {}

    for row in resp['reports']:
        report_date = row['startTime'].split('T')[0]
        download_url = row['downloadUrl']

        reports_dict[report_date] = download_url

    print(F"DONE: RUNNING list_job_reports")
    
    return reports_dict
```

I ran the function above on 2022-07-26, and the maximum date for a report generated was 2022-07-25 (same date as the job creation). Today, on 2022-07-28, I expected to have new reports, for 26th and 27th, but when I run `list_job_reports` now, the latest report is still the one for the 25th. It is as if the job didn't generate new daily reports automatically. I took a look at the documentation and I saw that just by creating a job, new reports should be generated daily (print below).

[image]

Did I miss something? Do I need to trigger the daily report generation somehow?